# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpRequest

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Found several of similar errors, but I don't think they apply. They talk about order of components, and I think I've tried everything.

I'm writing a new unit test for an existing service. Here's the service constructor:

```
@Injectable()
export class CreateSpAuthorizationUtility {
    constructor(
        private dialogService: DialogService,
        private router: Router,
        private store: Store<AppStore>,
        private noteService: NoteService,
        private stepperService: StepperService
    ) {
    }
}
```

And here's the unit test I wrote:

```
describe('Given a CreateSpAuthorizationUtility', () => {

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
            ],
            imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                AppConfig,
                HttpRequest,
                CreateSpAuthorizationUtility,
                {provide: DialogService, useClass: MockDialogService},
                {provide: NoteService, useClass: MockNoteService},
                {provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter},
                {provide: StepperService, useClass: StepperServiceMock},
                {provide: Store, useClass: TestStore}
            ]
        });
    }));

    it('should build query params',
        inject([CreateSpAuthorizationUtility, HttpTestingController, AppConfig],
            fakeAsync( (service: CreateSpAuthorizationUtility,
                        mockBackend: HttpTestingController,
                        appConfig: AppConfig,
                        router: MockRouter,
                        store: TestStore<AppStore>,
                        dialogService: MockDialogService,
                        noteService: MockNoteService,
                        stepperService: StepperServiceMock)  => {

                const prescreen: SpPrescreenSelectedValues = SP_PRESCREEN_SELECTED_VALUES_MOCK;
                service.buildQueryParams(prescreen, false);
            })));
});
```

And here's MockNoteService:

```
@Injectable()
export class MockNoteService extends NoteService {
    public static NON_EXISTING_ID = 'nonExistingId';

    public getNoteDefinition(noteDefinitionVisibleId: string): Observable<NoteDefinition> {
        if (noteDefinitionVisibleId === MockNoteService.NON_EXISTING_ID) {
            return observableThrowError('Test');
        }

        return of({
            id: '',
            version: 0,
            name: '',
            description: '',
            attributeDefs: [],
            visibleId: '',
            userCreatable: false,
            instanceCopyable: false,
            definitionEditable: false,
            isSystem: false,
            bodyRequired: true
        });
    }
}
```

Which extends NoteService:

```
export class NoteService extends BaseService {
    constructor(private http: HttpRequest, private appConfig: AppConfig, private store: Store<AppStore>) {
        super();
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpRequest: (?, ?, ?, ?).
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1021:1)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10922:1)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10815:1)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:11037:1)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:11046:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10984:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10944:1)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:10663:53)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:23876:1)
```

As I said, I've tried ordering and comparing with other unit tests in my project. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: I don't see imports but I assume you use original ``HttpRequest`` class with its implementation and **Testing module** have problems with that because it can not resolve parameters which are trying to inject.

Comment: @Buczkowski, I looked at HttpRequest and it takes HttpHeaders and HttpParams, but the test I'm coding from doesn't import these. I tried putting them in the imports section of the TestBed setup and it just confused it.

Comment: Remove it completely, you already provided Mocks for dependencies you are injecting in constructor.

Comment: @Buczkowski That got me:  Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NoteService -> HttpRequest]: 
   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NoteService -> HttpRequest]: 
     NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpRequest!

Comment: It means that ``NoteService`` have ``HttpRequest`` as a dependency or at least it's my thought but then it has less sense since you provide Mock for it...Can you show that ``MockNoteService``?

Comment: @Buczkowski done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187575/discussion-between-buczkowski-and-thom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, I made MockNoteService not extend from NoteService so that I didn't have the inheritance chain and that seemed to fix the problem.

Thanks, Buczkowski, for your help.